# alignmentGuide() not overriding child views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I initially align my child views to the `.top` by giving `alignment: .top` to my parent `HStack`.

I then want to have one child to the left (`.leading`) and the other child to the right (`.trailing`).

However this is not working, they are both in the center (screenshot below):

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("First")
                .alignmentGuide(.leading) { d in d[.leading] }
            Text("Second")
                .alignmentGuide(.trailing) { d in d[.trailing] }
        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        .padding(.top, 50)
    }
    
}
```

Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Alignment guides works differently. [This article should be helpful](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then want to have one child to the left (.leading) and the other child to the right (.trailing).

It can be achieved in much simpler way

```
HStack{
    Text("First")
    Spacer()
    Text("Second")
}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
```